# Cloudflare KV namespace doesn't bind

Tags: javascript, typescript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

Ran `wrangler dev` and it doesn't seem to bind Worker KV:

```
ERROR in /src/handler.ts
./src/handler.ts 16:8-17
[tsl] ERROR in /src/handler.ts(16,9)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'generalKV'.
```

Here is `handler.ts`:

```
async function postHandler(request: Request): Promise<Response> {
  let content = JSON.stringify(await request.json());
  await generalKV.put([Date.now().toString()], JSON.stringify(content));
  return new Response(content);
}
```

`wrangler.toml`:

```
name = "general-assignment"
type = "javascript"
account_id = "<id>"
workers_dev = true
compatibility_date = "2021-11-01"
kv_namespaces = [ 
    { binding = "generalKV", id = "<id>", preview_id = "<id>" }
]
```

Some suggests change `kv_namespaces` to `kv-namespaces`, but it doesn't work for me. Please inform me if I missed anything else.

Comment: The error doesn't seem like it's from Wrangler or Workers, but from Typescript or some typescript related tool (tsl). It seems like you need to tell your compiler that it can expect `generalKV` to be available at runtime, so that it doesn't complain about it being undefined _during compilation_.

Comment: @Brett Sounds reasonable, could you elaborate on how to let compiler expect `generalKV` to be available, since the documents says a global variable will be created after binding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For readers that come to this question via Google and use Wrangler v2 and get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: MY_KV is not defined

The tutorials and examples neglect a second parameter (and a third parameter). This second parameter holds the *environment*. You can use and bind to `kv` with these steps:

```sh
# Create the KV namespaces
wrangler kv:namespace create "MY_KV" &&\
wrangler kv:namespace create "MY_KV" --preview
```

`wrangler` complains if there is no preview KV, so create them both. Next, create a `kv_namespaces` array entry and duplicate the `preview_id` in the default (dev) section (denoted as `yyyy` below).

```yaml
# wrangler.toml
name = "worker"
main = "src/index.js"
compatibility_date = "2022-04-14"
account_id = "...."
workers_dev = true

routes = [
    "exmample.com/*"
]

# Duplicate preview_id to id
kv_namespaces = [
    { binding = "MY_KV", preview_id = "yyyy", id = "yyyy" }
]

# Run `wrangler publish --env production` when happy
[env.production]
kv_namespaces = [
    { binding = "MY_KV", id = "xxxx" }
]
```

You can then bind to kv like so:

```js
# index.js
export default {
  async fetch(request, env) {
  ...
  const someKV = env.MY_KV.get("some-key");
  ...
  }
```

Comment: As always... a nice little bug. Without "preview_id", the binding won't add. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Mecanik was stuck for so long on this thank you so much haha it was preview id

Answer (score 0):

Did you already manually create the KV namespace on Cloudflare? I don't believe it creates them dynamically from the binding setup in worker (yet).

Documentation for creating via Wrangler -

https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/cli-wrangler/commands#create

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes I already created them; I tried creating KV namespace from both CLI and web, and I can see them on my Worker KV. But still it doesn't bind.

Comment: You might want to also take a look at your typescript setup to have it match this - https://github.com/cloudflare/workers-types Specifically the bindings section might be what's missing?

Comment: Seems like all that I missed is the declaration in the `bindings.d.ts`, it works now, thank you so much!